# Не вносятся юзеры в бд. Дискорд, sqlite3, Python

Tags: python, база-данных, discord, sqlite3

Что в создании этой таблицы не так? Почему в базу данных не вносятся все участники, в самой базе данных есть только сам бот, помогите, желательно с объяснением
Вот код:

```
        @client.event
        async def on_ready():
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                name TEXT,
                id INT,
                cash BIGINT,
                rep INT,
                lvl INT )""")
            connection.commit()

            for guild in client.guilds:
                for member in guild.members:
                    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                        connection.commit()            
                    else:
                        pass
            print('Бот запущен')
```

Comment: вы поставили галочки SERVER MEMBERS INTENT и PRESENCE INTENT в настройках бота во вкладке bot на сайте?

Comment: да, конечно поставил